# Bootstrap navbar dropdown not appearing correctly using ruby link_to method

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I would like help in correcting a small problem with the appearance of my dropdown menu in my bootstrap navbar. I used the ruby link_to method to create the links for the dropdown menu, which are functioning correctly, except that the drop down element is not appearing in line with the rest of the navbar elements.
This is the current code I have for the navbar:

Here is a link with an image of the problem:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dmrs87xr2kbkat3/dropdown%20problem.jpg?dl=0

```html
<li class="active"><%= link_to "Main", root_path %>
    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <%= link_to "Employee Profile", profile_path, :class => "dropdown-toggle", :data => {:toggle => "dropdown"}, :role => "button", :aria => {:expanded => "false"} %>
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">  
        <li><a href="#">Tasks / Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vacations</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Note: I managed to partially fix the problem by adding a  tag between the <% link to ...%> the  tag, but that disables the bootstap styling from the element and renders it in regular html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you must include `<span class="caret"></span>` inside link.

try this

```
<%= link_to profile_path, :class => "dropdown-toggle", :data => {:toggle => "dropdown"}, :role => "button", :aria => {:expanded => "false"} do %>Employee Profile <span class="caret"></span> <% end %>
```

Comment: I replaced my code with the code you suggested, however im now getting a NoMethodError regarding that code line for some reason. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, there was a typo. I just updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="dropdown div-inline">
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-option dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Show Dropdown
         <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">      
                    <li role="presentation">
                         <a href=""> First link</a>
                    </li>  
                    <li role="presentation">
                         <a href=""> Second link</a>
                    </li>  
                    <li role="presentation">
                         <a href=""> Third link</a>
                    </li>  
         </ul>
    </div>
```

**Try this** and visit [Bootstrap dropdown examples](http://www.bootply.com/tagged/dropdown) to get many examples that suit your need.